# Why doesn't this Taylor series for exponentiation work?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, exponentiation

Don't know if this is more mathematics or programming. Anyway I want to implement an efficient way to approximate exponentiation involving non-integral exponents, faster than C++'s pow from cmath.

I just found this series [online](https://www.efunda.com/math/taylor_series/exponential.cfm):

$a^x = 1 + x \ln  a + \frac{(x \ln  a) ^ 2} {2} + \frac{(x \ln  a) ^ 3} {6} + \frac{(x \ln a) ^ 4} {24}...$

So I implemented it in Python:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

f = 1
factorials = np.array([(f := f * i) for i in range(1, 17)], dtype=np.int64)

@nb.njit(cache=True, fastmath=True)
def taylor(base: float, exp: float, lim: int) -> float:
    c = exp * log(base)
    f = 1
    s = 1
    for i in range(lim):
        f *= c
        s += f / factorials[i]
    
    return s
```

And it seems to work well for exponents between 0 and 1, but doesn't work at all for exponents greater than 1:

```
In [397]: taylor(256, 1/3, 16)
Out[397]: 6.34960420776535

In [398]: 256**(1/3)
Out[398]: 6.3496042078727974

In [399]: taylor(256, 3, 16)
Out[399]: 8441719.024421709

In [400]: 256**3
Out[400]: 16777216

In [401]: taylor(256, 2, 16)
Out[401]: 61649.26195536944

In [402]: 256**2
Out[402]: 65536

In [403]: taylor(256, 1, 16)
Out[403]: 255.9821624637957

In [404]: taylor(256, 0.5, 16)
Out[404]: 15.999999887823558
```

I implemented the same logic as the series shown above, so the series must be the cause.

Was I lied to? Is the series wrong?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I made it before looking at the series you mentioned at all and it's clear that the series you give is indeed convergent everywhere. Honestly more than likely the problem is not conceptual but instead is a problem with rate of convergence. Not to mention that it's difficult for computers to be good at precise decimal computations

Comment: Usually, you would reduce the exponent to a small[tm] range, e.g. by dividing by it by 2 an appropriate number of times. Then square the final result to compensate. In your implementation however, the value dropped into Taylor for e^x is x > 16 for 256^3. So slow convergence and increased rounding errors may occur. Also evaluation of power series like this has bad conditioning.  Just consider 16^17 / 17! for an estimate of error.

Comment: The bigger the exponent, the more terms you have to take if you want to use the series directly. You are using 16 all the time. But higher terms become more difficult to evaluate accurately because n! and nth power are huge. It's not usually a good idea to use the series directly unless $x$ is small.

Comment: And once you reduced the exponents to lie within a known interval, you'd not use Taylor because it is suboptimal. Better use best polynomial for e^x and that interval, see Remez algorithm for how to compute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given Taylor series is correct. However, when you truncate it at $n$ terms, the remaining error will be on a similar scale to the next term in the series - for example, if you calculate the value using three terms, i.e.

$$a^x \approx 1 + x \ln a + \frac{(x \ln a)^2}{2}$$

then the error will be on the order of $\frac{(x \ln a)^3}{6}$. This means that as $x$ gets larger, the error is going to also increase. And it also grows in relative terms - for any $a > 1$, the exponential function $a^x$ *always* eventually grows faster than *any* polynomial in $x$ as $x$ goes to infinity. If you're calculating 20 terms rather than 3 then it will take longer to reach a significant divergence, but there will always be a point where you lose control of the error.

One method to avoid this problem is roughly:

1. Shift and/or scale $x$ to put it in a particular range, e.g. find an integer $n$ such that $x_0 = \frac{x}{2^n} \in [1, 2]$.
2. Calculate $a^{x_0}$ to some desired accurately with a suitable method (as mentioned in the comments, there are often better options than Taylor approximations).
3. Calculate $(a^{x_0})^{2^n}$ via repeated squaring.

Even in this case, the squaring step is going to cause the error from step 2 to potentially accumulate. This is why it's common to calculate exponents via other methods, such as via a log-transformation.

Answer (score 0):

The series is not wrong, you can obtain it from the exponential series. In fact, recall that $a^x=e^{x\log a}$, substituting in the exponential series you have:
$$a^x=e^{x\log a}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(x\log a)^k}{k!}=1+x\log a+\frac{(x\log a)^2}{2}+\dots $$